# Calculation with values from a text file and write into another text file

Tags: c++, text-files, ifstream

I want to grab some values from a text file and multiply those values with a fixed number in c++. Then I want to write the solution for every value into another text file. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

std::ifstream infile("Test_60.txt");
std::ofstream outfile("Output.txt");

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double max, min, d, s, m;
    max = 0;
    min = 1;
    double x, y, z, R, G, B;
    while (infile >> x >> y >> z >> R >> G >> B)
    {
        if (max < x)
        {
            max = x;
        }

        if (min > x)
        {
            min = x;
        }

        d = max - min;
        s = 60 / d;
        m = s*x;
    }

    outfile << m << endl;
    infile.close();
    outfile.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The Minimum and Maximum is already working but when I try to write it into a text file I get only one value for `x` (or `m`).
In the end I want a text file with multiplied values for x and y and the values from my input file for z,R,G,B.

Best regards.

Comment: Your output stream calls need to be inside the while loop, no?

Comment: I think you need two loops, one for finding the max and min values, then, after calculating the multiplicative factor, one to evaluate the new values for x (and y?) and write them into the second file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put statements

```
max = 0;
min = 1;
```

into while loop so that you ensure the min/max reset.